# An isolated Earth

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

It is known the fact that there is no way to extract energy (in any form) from any system without introducing some energy. The Earth for example, gets energy from the Sun, from nuclear fusion of hydrogen. But, what if the Earth would be isolated (there is neither an energy gain, neither loss), it would be possible for our lives to continue (without using an fuel on the Earth)?

The idea of this question started from the quote "Nothing is lost, nothing is created, everything is transformed". As the energy remains inside the system, may it be transformed to be reused?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine we put the Earth and most of its atmosphere in a big box which does not absorb any energy (on the outside and inside). In this case, you are essentially bringing the scale of the universe down. Whatever processes continue the entropy of the universe would still increase, and due to the its small size we will reach heat death a lot faster.

However, without the sun and without using any other fuel on Earth I do not see how we could survive. How do you propose we harness and recycle whatever energy is "floating" around inside the box?